# app works in simulator but closes in my iPhone

Tags: ios

I tried to search without success.

Im using Xcode and when I run my app in the simulator it works without any problem. But when I run it on my real device, iPhone 6s the app closes immediately when I press the app icon to open it.

I even tried to start a new empty project but the same problem occurs.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Apple's membership center and buy yourself a developer program membership:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/

You will then be able to develop apps and run them on your device without the limitations imposed by the free trial-type membership, which you are now encountering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess ill have to do that. But isn't it supposed to have an app for 7 days from the day that you upload it into your phone?

Comment: There are various limitations with the free trial; I don't know what they all are. But the open-and-quick-close that you are getting, even on a new project, shows clearly that you are encountering one of them. :(